# Bash while loop with if statement stuck in true loop

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm working on a battery notification script.

Apologies that this is piecey debug code at the moment.

Here is the code I have so far...

```
#!/bin/bash

BatteryCapacity=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity`
BatteryStatus=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status`
BatteryFull="Full"
BatteryDischarging="Discharging"
BatteryCharging="Charging"
CriticalAlert=97
NormalAlert=96
LowAlert=95
i=0

while true 
do
    if [ "$BatteryStatus" = "$BatteryDischarging" ]; then
        if [ $BatteryCapacity -le $CriticalAlert ]; then
            notify-send -u critical "Alert" "Battery Low!!!"
            echo "Success01"
            sleep 10

    else 
        if [ "A" = "A" ]; then 
            echo "Success02"
            sleep 10

            fi  
        fi  
    fi
done
```

When $BatteryStatus = Discharging (Discharging = Discharging) and $BatteryCapacity = $CriticalAlert (I change this value around when debugging this program to match actual battery capacity) the program will successfully meet the first set of conditions and echo "Success01".

```
+ '[' Discharging = Discharging ']'
+ '[' 97 -le 97 ']'
+ notify-send -u critical Alert 'Battery Low!!!'
+ echo 'Success 001'
Success 001
+ sleep 10
```

But if my $BatteryStatus is not equal to Discharging and is Charging or Full the program will get stuck in...

```
+ '[' Charging = Discharging ']'
+ true
+ '[' Charging = Discharging ']'
+ true
+ '[' Charging = Discharging ']'
+ true
+ '[' Charging = Discharging ']'
+ true
...
```

I'm confused as to why the program gets stuck in the `+ '[' Charging = Discharging ']' + true` loop instead of moving on to the else condition.

I'm using `bash -x SCRIPT.sh` for the debug output.

I've tried searching online but I can't find anything that tells me what I might be doing wrong.

Here's a [link](https://github.com/enigmatic-system/battery-notification2.0/blob/master/bat-notify.sh) to the more sane version 2 of the battery-notification script to give some context into what I am doing.

Anyone care to take a explain?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your indentation doesn't match the actual structure of the `if`/`else`/`fi`s. That `else` clause relates to the `if [ $BatteryCapacity -le $CriticalAlert ]`, not the `if [ "$BatteryStatus" = "$BatteryDischarging" ]`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson 

Yeahhh I see how I'm playing against syntax... 

I rewrote the whole thing using different organization of conditions.

Comment: Also instead of back-tick sub-shell to extract `/sys` values: `read -r BatteryCapacity </sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity; read -r BatteryStatus </sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status`

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced the closing `fi` after the first `sleep 10`

With correct indentation you code looks like this:

```
if [ "$BatteryStatus" = "$BatteryDischarging" ]; then
    if [ $BatteryCapacity -le $CriticalAlert ]; then
        notify-send -u critical "Alert" "Battery Low!!!"
        echo "Success01"
        sleep 10
    else 
        if [ "A" = "A" ]; then 
            echo "Success02"
            sleep 10
        fi  
    fi  
fi
```

You can see that the A=A match is an else to the Capacity check, not the Status.

You can move the `fi` or rewrite the logc. Something like this:

```
while sleep 10; do
    if [ "$BatteryStatus" = "$BatteryDischarging" ] && [ $BatteryCapacity -le $CriticalAlert ]; then
            notify-send -u critical "Alert" "Battery Low!!!"
            echo "Success01"
    elif [ "A" = "A" ]; then 
            echo "Success02"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up we writing the whole script.

I see how your ```while sleep 10; do``` works though, and I haven't seen that before. Although my scope is still mildly limited. I did need variation in times though for different sections. 

Here's the final product. 
https://github.com/enigmatic-system/battery-notification3.0/blob/master/bat-notify.sh